# How to use sqlite3_mprintf() with UTF-16 strings?

Tags: c++, unicode, sqlite, utf-16

Why there is no sqlite3_mprintf16() function? I need the '%q' functionality but for UTF-16 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why there is no sqlite3_mprintf16() function?

Because SQLite is not infected by UTF-16 yet. It uses UTF-8 almost everywhere in the interface, and so there's no point in formatting a query encoded in UTF-16 string.

> I need the '%q' functionality but for UTF-16 string.

This is a different story. What you need is something like '%q16', which in fact doesn't exist.

Said that, you shall not use `sqlite3_mprintf` at all. Use prepared statements and bind functions instead. They do allow you to bind a UTF-16 string using `sqlite3_bind_text16`. Even better, [stop using UTF-16 for your strings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/102205/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful).

Comment: I know about the problems of UTF-16. My task is to port a plugin of a certain Windows application from an old version (which used char* for strings) to a new one (which uses wchar_t* everywhere), so converting all strings from UTF-16 to UTF-8 and vice versa is undesirable. But you're right - I have to use prepared statements.

Comment: SQLite *is* "infected by UTF-16".  It has `sqlite_open16`, `sqlite3_prepare16`, etc.